# How to have Word keep list paragraphs together but not with the following text?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

While I can easily set up a style template for lists to have the "keep with next" paragraph option, it is usually convenient to have the very last item of a list *not* having this option such that a page break between the list and the following text is actually permitted. But is there any way to have this automatically applied instead of having to manually change the last item's pagination option?

Comment: @Máté Thanks, didn't see that one

Comment: @Oliver Why is this specific to 2010?

Comment: You added the tag, not me.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg sorry, I misread the log - why did you remove the general tag? I chose 2010 since that's the version I used, but I'd guess this applies to most other versions as well

Comment: Well, we usually keep the more specific tag. If you think the question applies to many different versions, just use the general tag. A user who searches for "microsoft word" will find either tag anyway. But someone who is looking for a specific version needs the versioned tag. There's also an ancient question about this on meta, but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you really want to use is the `Keep Lines Together` option instead of the `Keep with Next` option. Then you should not need a special style for the last item. The `Keep with Next` option is just preventing page breaks between paragraphs (which is most likely not what you want for lists made of larger paragraphs; you wouldn't want to chop off only the last item in your lists). `Keep Lines Together` is going to prevent your individual list item paragraphs from being broken up with page breaks (which is probably what you want for larger list items).

After experimenting with this a little, it seems that both together produce the best results.

More explaination: http://www.worldstart.com/ms-word-keep-with-next-vs-keep-lines-together/